# Can't create an entity framework in visual studio 2015

Tags: c#, mysql, asp.net, database, visual-studio

I need to create an ADO entity framework from a MySQL database.

I've installed the .NET connector and the Visual Studio extension for MySql.

I can see the connection, even create a new one, but when I press "next" the window closes automatically and I can't do anything else...

EntityFramework, mysql.data and mysql.data.entity are correctly installed... But I can't fix this one.

Comment: This is a known bug in Connector/NET: [Bug 89338](https://bugs.mysql.com/bug.php?id=89338). According to that bug report, it's possible that deleting the obsolete `MySql.Data.dll` and `MySql.Data.Entity.dll` files in the Visual Studio `Common7\IDE\PrivateAssemblies` directory may work around the problem.